# Adding colour overlay to greyscale image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm wanting to add pre-generated heatmaps over photographs. The colours in the images aren't important and to make the heatmap colours stand out I'm making the images greyscale. I've done this using

```py
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

However the greyscale image now has one fewer dimensions compared to the heatmap (which is BRG). How can I overlay the heatmap on top of the grey image?

Answer (score 1):

With the two identical size and mode images in place, execute the following code.

```
from PIL import Images

im_1 = Image.open("/constr/pics1/100_canary.png")   

#  mode is RGBA 

im_2 = Image.open("/constr/pics1/100_cockcrow.png")

# Check on mode, size and format first for compatibility. 

# Make both modes the same 

im_4 = Image.blend(im_1, im_2, 0.5) 

im_4.show()
```

Comment: Sorry, the heatmap is a separate image, not one generated from the greyscale image. I want to overlap this heatmap in colour over the grey image.

Comment: With or without transperency. So that each image form 50 percent of the final image?Can you use PIL Images library?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I want the greyscale image with a transparent heatmap over the top

Comment: This is how to overlay 2 images with fifty percent each, you can change the percentages. This helped?

Comment: This only works if the images are the same type though: the problem I have is that the greyscale image is of shape [x, y] but the heatmap is RGB, so [x, y, 3]

Comment: Use this fuction: im_2 = im_2.convert("RGBA")